# How can i sort Jquery Datatable currency Column properly?

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I am  using  Datatables  Version 1.10.12  and  jquery-1.11.1

My  currency  column  doesn't sort properly,below is the code I am using to sort

```
$(document).ready( function () {
        $('#notSoCoolGrid').DataTable({
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            columnDefs: [{ type: 'currency', targets: 1 }],
            "aaSorting": [[ 2, 'asc' ]]
        } );
    } );
```

And I am getting as shown below for my currency column.Please  note   brackets(  ) are considered negative number

($75.00) USD

($108.87) USD

($249.44) USD

($1,000.00) USD

£899.00 GBP

$905.00 AUD

£830.65 GBP

$825.00 USD

£59.67 GBP

Comment: I am new to Datatable..How do you  implement that?

Comment: You have your value in different currency formats? So what should your sort be like? I mean when you do ascending do you want to convert all the values into a common currency type (dollar) and then sort from small to high?

Comment: I want to consider    AUD,GBP rate conversion..currently I think it check out only dollars

Comment: Danny the rates change everyday.. their is no fix conversation rate. I think you need to use some API and convert the rates.. Also having them with different currency format and sorting is confusing for the user on the screen. May be you can add one more column with converted currency data in any one format ..

Answer (score 2):

Use [brackets-negative](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/brackets-negative) sorting plug-in. Your code can stay the same, you just need to include extra JS file `//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.13/sorting/brackets-negative.js`.

Comment: He also wants to convert his currency rates and then sort. Is it something that is possible with only client side code.?

Answer (score 0):

Below is what  finally  works out for me,i have to consider the exchange rate as well.

```
<link href="datatables/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTable.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jQuery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="datatables/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
            var currencies = { GBP: 1.2403, AUD: 0.7364, USD: 1 };
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order['currencies-pre'] = function(d) {
                var sign = /\([^)]*\)/.test(d)?-1:1;
                var currency = currencies[d.match(/USD|GBP|AUD/).pop()]; // /!\ all MUST have currency
                var n = d.replace(/[^\d.]/g,"");
                console.log(sign * n * currency);
                return sign * n * currency;
            };
            $('#notSoCoolGrid').DataTable({
                "aoColumns": [{ sWidth: "10%", bSearchable: false, bSortable: false }, { sWidth: "90%", bSearchable: false, bSortable: true }],
                "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "columnDefs": [{ type: 'currencies', targets: 1 }],
                "aaSorting": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
            });
        });
    </script>
```